# How will make sure my library support upnp 1.1

Tags: upnp

I have an upnp library .Am making it to work as a controlled device.It works fine with UPNP 1.0 standard.**How will I make sure that it will gracefully handle UPNP 1.1 controlpoint/control device request as well**.
There is no doccumentation for library :(
I searched in the source code for new headers **like BOOTID etc** .No new headers(according to 1.1) are found in the code ..
Is there any way to make sure that my solution will work with 1.0 and 1.1 as well.

Regards
Varunjith

Answer (score 1):

v1.1 is backward compatible with v1.0 so any well behaved control point should work perfectly well against your v1.0 device.

Thinking about it more, I'm not sure v1.1 even contains any additional control point features. While it would be possible for a badly written control point to assume the presence of v1.1 headers in device messages, there are so many v1.0 devices out there that any such buggy control point would be quickly noticed and fixed.

Which is all a roundabout way of saying that I think you can already be confident your solution will work with v1.1.